# Akka streams dynamic filters

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm attempting to create a dynamic list of filters because I need to filter on 100's of items and for each item apply a function, I do not want to explicitly define an outlet for each filter so have defined dynamic filters  :

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ClosedShape
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Broadcast, Flow, GraphDSL, Merge, RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}


object DynamicFilters extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

  case class Person(name: String, age: Double)
  val filterNames = List("1" , "2" , "3");
  val printSink = Sink.foreach[Person](println)
  val input = Source(List(Person("1", 30),Person("1", 20),Person("1", 20),Person("1", 30),Person("2", 2)))

  val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
    GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Person](filterNames.size))
      val merge = builder.add(Merge[Person](filterNames.size))

      input ~> broadcast

      for(index <- 0 to filterNames.size-1){
        println("Adding filter")
        val fi = Flow[Person].filter(f => f.name.equalsIgnoreCase(filterNames(index)))
        broadcast.out(index) ~> fi ~> merge
      }
      merge ~> printSink

      ClosedShape

    }
  )

  graph.run()
}
```

This solution seems 'hacky', is there an alternative method using Akka streams for filtering on many items within a graph without defining a custom outlet for each ?

Comment: Why not `input.via(Flow[Person].filter(person => filterNames.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase(person.name)))).to(printSink).run()`?

Comment: For the broadcast into merge, note that you'll get up to n emissions of every element.  Is that intended?

Comment: @LeviRamsey yes, for each emission I plan to apply a function to each filtered stream of elements.

Comment: would that function be after the merge?  I was pointing out that the merge will emit each incoming element however many times it passed a filter.

Comment: @LeviRamsey before the merge, irregardless I'm thinking a groupBy is a better solution.

Comment: You have a `List[A => Boolean]` right? And you need to filter the elements of an Akka stream that doesn't satisfy all the filters, right?

Comment: @invzbl3 yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode, it'd look like this, but it's quite a working option:

```
def filterAll[A](stream: AkkaStrem[A])(filters: List[A => Boolean]): AkkaStrem[A] =
  stream.filter(a => filters.forall(p => p(a)))
```

The point and trick is to do a single filter using forall.

If there are many cpu intensive tasks, then the threads in the pool will only perform them. And Akka pool is not intended for this - Akka pool serves Akka.